# C++ switch case, "default" doesn't work

Tags: c++, switch-statement, arduino-uno

Hello i'm just beginning with programming in **C++** with my **Arduino Uno**.
Now I want to make something like a Living Color. I make this step by step and now my last problem is that the lights doesn't go out, when I have my next case.

The first part is not really important (I know it can be better).
But the problem for me is in the last part: `default`.

I hope someone will explain me what i am doing wrong so the lights will go off after each one, and I can change the brightness of each one, and maybe also other suggestions.

Sorry for my bad English.

**Code**

```
#define BUTTON_PIN2 10

const int RGB_LED_BLUE = 6;
const int RGB_LED_GREEN = 5;
const int RGB_LED_RED = 3;
const int POTPIN = A0;

int color = 0;
int x = 0;
int potmeter = 0;

boolean button_state = LOW;
boolean current_button_state = LOW;
boolean previous_button_state = LOW;


void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(BUTTON_PIN2, INPUT);
  pinMode(RGB_LED_BLUE,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(RGB_LED_GREEN,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(RGB_LED_RED,OUTPUT);

}

void loop()
  {
    current_button_state = digitalRead (BUTTON_PIN2);
    if ((current_button_state == HIGH)&&
    (current_button_state != previous_button_state))
    color = x=x+1;

switch(color)
    {
      case 1:
        {
        potmeter = analogRead(POTPIN);
        potmeter = potmeter /4;
        analogWrite (RGB_LED_RED, potmeter);
        }

      break;

      case 2:
        {
        potmeter = analogRead(POTPIN);
        potmeter = potmeter /4;
        analogWrite (RGB_LED_GREEN, potmeter);
        }
      break;

      case 3:
        {
        potmeter = analogRead(POTPIN);
        potmeter = potmeter /4;
        analogWrite (RGB_LED_BLUE, potmeter);
        x=0;
        }
      break;

      default:
        {
        analogWrite (RGB_LED_RED, LOW);
        analogWrite (RGB_LED_GREEN, LOW);
        analogWrite (RGB_LED_BLUE, LOW);
        }
     }
   previous_button_state = current_button_state;
   delay(10);
 }
```

Comment: The problem is almost certainly in the code executed by default (i.e. in your `analogueWrite()` function).   Since that is a non-standard function, nobody can help you - it's not like people can telepathically deduce what some unknown function is supposed to do and identify bugs within it.

Comment: @Peter it is a standard Arduino function https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/AnalogWrite

Comment: @Eelke - Having tagged the question C++, the OP is drawing the attention of C++ developers in general - not just those who know about arduino - and expecting them to be able to help.   That is also suggested in the way the question is asked - implying the problem is in the working of a language feature (`switch`/`default`).    If that is the expectation, the onus is on the OP to justify that claim - i.e. justify a belief that the function is being called correctly to achieve the desired results.   Otherwise, the question should not be tagged C++.

Comment: @Peter It's pretty standard to tag every question with the language it's written in, even if the question is actually about some specific non-standard API/extension. But yes, the question should be rephrased to ask about Arduino usage, and not try to blame the C++ feature.

Answer (score 2):

You are resetting x to 0 in case 3 and then it is increases again before the switch and before it is assigned to color so color only gets the values 1,2 and 3. It never is a value that will trigger the default clause.

Moving the `x=0;` statement to the default clause would let it reach 4 to trigger the default.